# CONFIG_SPL_BUILD seems to be not defined during spl program build in u-boot? Why?

Tags: gdb, u-boot

While running u-boot-spl on the qemu-arm64 virt machine, using u-boot.v2022.07, I was folloing the code using gdb and when it was in this function below (in common/init/board_init.c), the program counter skips the code wrapped by #if CONFIG_VAL(SYS_MALLOC_F_LEN) ~  #endif macro.

```
ulong board_init_f_alloc_reserve(ulong top)
{
    /* Reserve early malloc arena */
#if CONFIG_VAL(SYS_MALLOC_F_LEN)
    top -= CONFIG_VAL(SYS_MALLOC_F_LEN);
#endif
    /* LAST : reserve GD (rounded up to a multiple of 16 bytes) */
    top = rounddown(top-sizeof(struct global_data), 16);

    return top;
}
```

But according to include/linux/kconfig.h,

```
/*  
 * CONFIG_VAL(FOO) evaluates to the value of
 *  CONFIG_TOOLS_FOO if USE_HOSTCC is defined,
 *  CONFIG_FOO if CONFIG_SPL_BUILD is undefined,
 *  CONFIG_SPL_FOO if CONFIG_SPL_BUILD is defined.
 *  CONFIG_TPL_FOO if CONFIG_TPL_BUILD is defined.
 *  CONFIG_VPL_FOO if CONFIG_VPL_BUILD is defined.
 */
#define CONFIG_VAL(option)  config_val(option)
```

Because I was running u-boot-spl, CONFIG_VAL(SYS_MALLOC_F_LEN) is evalated as CONFIG_SPL_SYS_MALLOC_F_LEN and my .config file shows

```
CONFIG_SPL_SYS_MALLOC_F_LEN=0x2000000
```

I'm pretty sure u-boot-spl and u-boot was built using this .config file and spl/u-boot.cfg shows CONFIG_SPL_BUILD=1 during the spl program build.
Why does it skip the code when the value is defined? What could I be missing out?

Comment: Please re-check what you're building and testing for, on v2022.07 qemu_arm64_defconfig doesn't even enable SPL.

Comment: @TomRini Hi, Thank you. I forgot I modified the qemu_arm64_defconfig to try to include SPL(once I saw SPL->PROPER running). and now I realize SPL was not originally supported in arm64 qemu machine and I asked another question in unix/linux stackexchange. If you can spare a little time, please look at my question.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747464/testing-u-boot-on-qemu-arm64-virtual-machine